# How to use a serial field with Postgresql with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, ef-code-first

I have a serial field (called displayID) that is not the key of the table in a postgresql database and I am working with entity framework code first.  When I add new objects into the database through the context, I save the object but it inserts into the database with a value of 0 rather than the next integer.  I can't get it to auto-increment the value in the database. I'm using devArt postgres entity framework driver. Is there something special I have to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the Identity Data Annotation to your displayID property. Don't know if the DevArt stuff supports that but it should work.

```
public class Foo
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int displayID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int myKey { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

**2020 update** it is only enough to set UseIdentityAlwaysColumn in IEntityTypeConfiguration

```
builder.Property(x => x.displayID).UseIdentityAlwaysColumn();
```

Comment: I just saw that there is also an extension method `builder.UseSerialColumn()`. Just a note for future browsers (info is related to Core 3.1 / EF 3.1).

Comment: It think is avaible only from .net 5